# xcopy from same location but different computers

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

How do I do this? After copying the files, I need them to be renamed to their origin's computer name.

I got

```
for %%a in (computerlist.txt) do xcopy %%a\C$\file.txt D:\ /C
```

Will this work? I'm lost in the renaming part though.

It seems like %%a in \%%a\C$\file.txt is not accepted. When I run it, it becomes \computerlist.txt\C$\file.txt. Same with the destination path. I even tried to put the full path of computerlist.txt inside the parenthesis but still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, this should get you started:

```
for /f %%a in (computerlist.txt) do xcopy \\%%a\C$\file.txt D:\%%a.txt /C
```

If `computerlist.txt` has the leading `\\` in the computer name, remove them from the `xcopy \\%%a` portion of the line.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I don't need to make multiple directories. I want to rename the files instead.

Comment: It seems like %%a in \\%%a\C$\file.txt is not accepted. When I run it, it becomes \\computerlist.txt\C$\file.txt. Same with the destination path.

Comment: My mistake. See the latest edit. (Forgot the `/f` switch to `for`.)